# Regular expression to match simple "id" values?

Tags: java, regex

I need regex for a line that starts with two characters followed by 2-4 digits or 2-4 digits followed by "-" and followed by 2-4 digits.

Examples:

- AB125
- AC123-25
- BT1-2535

Seems simple , but I got stuck with it ...

Comment: For context (and better responses), it's generally good to post what regular expression/code that has been tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular expressions *always* seem simple, right up to the point where you try to use them :-)

This particular one can be done with something along the lines of:

```
^[A-Z]{2}([0-9]{2,4}-)?[0-9]{2,4}$
```

That's:

- 2 alpha (uppercase) characters.
- an optional 2-to-4-digit and hyphen sequence.
- a mandatory 2-to-4-digit sequence.
- start and end markers.

That last one, `BT1-2535`, doesn't match your textual specification by the way since it only has *one* digit before the hyphen. I'm assuming that was a typo. You will also have to change the character bit to use `[A-Za-z]` if you want to allow lowercase as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation :)
Regarding BT1-2535 , I meant it , and i changed your regex to match it
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
^[A-Z]{2}\d{2,4}(?:-\d{2,4})?
```

This matches two uppercase letters followed by 2-4 digits, followed by (optionally) a hyphen and another 2-4 digits.